# What's the right way to have Drush make automatically add version numbers to my info files?

Tags: drush

Everything I read says Drush should be able to automatically rewrite my info files to add version numbers (and the only switch I see is the switch to disable this, --no-gitinfofile), yet nothing I am doing seems to make this work.

The Drush make command being run is:

```
drush make --working-copy --no-core -y --contrib-destination=. profile.make
```

A sample project in the make file would look like this:

```
; Sample Project
projects[sample_project][type] = "module"
projects[sample_project][download][type] = "git"
projects[sample_project][download][url] = "gitlab@git.example.com:cms/sample_project.git"
projects[sample_project][download][tag] = "7.x-1.5"
projects[sample_project][subdir] = "custom"
```

Googling around, I found the following options to maybe try, none of which worked:

```
projects[sample_project][download][version] = "7.x-1.5"
projects[sample_project][download][full_version] = "7.x-1.5"
projects[sample_project][version] = "7.x-1.5"
projects[sample_project][full_version] = "7.x-1.5"
```

The Drush version is 6.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my makefile:

```
api = 2
core = 7.x

projects[drupal][version] = "7.26"

;===============================================================================
; Ctools
;===============================================================================

projects[ctools][type] = module
projects[ctools][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[ctools][download][type] = git
projects[ctools][download][revision] = e720f61
projects[ctools][download][branch] = 7.x-1.x
projects[ctools][download][full_version] = 7.x-1.x-dev
```

I run it like so:
drush make --working-copy --no-cache --no-core my_make_file.make

For a good overview of the drush make flags: 
http://www.drushcommands.com/drush-6x/make/make

In my case version info wasn't written because I had --no-gitinfofile in my script for some reason. I hope this helps!

Comment: Drush 6.x will only add version numbers to modules hosted on drupal.org.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there's been a bug report about it and it can work in Drush 7.

Issue about it here:
https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/368

Fixed by this commit:
https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/commit/26f44a44caa0284f052873023ae08f457da5e5d1

Fixed in Drush 6 by pulling in the commit and using the --force-gitinfofile switch.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Drush 7, you can use the `drush make` switch `--force-gitinfofile` to get the version numbers added to .info files.

```
--force-gitinfofile : Force a modification of .info files when cloning from Git even if repository isn't hosted on Drupal.org.
```

Once you have that switch, then the version number like below will work:

`projects[sample_project][version] = "7.x-1.5"`

I have found that this works even if you specify a git path and revision:

```
projects[sample_project][version] = "7.x-1.5"
projects[sample_project][download][type] = "git"
projects[sample_project][download][url] = "https://git.drupalcode.org/project/sample_project.git"
projects[sample_project][branch] = "7.x"
projects[sample_project][revision] = "9320560c"
```